# Why doesn't printf "${array[@]}\n" print all elements of my array?

Tags: unix, ksh

I have some values in an array called pwd_ids, when I am trying to print all the values with printf it is giving only first element, while trying to print with echo it is giving all the elements. what is the reason behind this. below given my example.

```
set -A pwd_ids  E.1.1.7 E.1.1.9 E.1.1.2 E.1.1.3 E.1.1.4 E.1.1.6 E.1.1.5 
echo "${pwd_ids[@]}"
printf "${pwd_ids[@]}\n"
```

Output:

```
 E.1.1.7 E.1.1.9 E.1.1.2 E.1.1.3 E.1.1.4 E.1.1.6 E.1.1.5
 E.1.1.7
```

Comment: bash is not ksh

Comment: As Cyrus says -- the bash tag should not be used for questions with code only valid in ksh.

Comment: Thanks Cyrus and Charles for feedback, I was mistakenly given bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `printf` is the *format string*. Data should be passed only in *subsequent* arguments. Thus:

```
printf '%s\n' "${pwd_ids[@]}"
```

will properly emit:

```
E.1.1.7
E.1.1.9
E.1.1.2
E.1.1.3
E.1.1.4
E.1.1.6
E.1.1.5
```

Other format strings can be used as well; to print your items with a dash before them, for instance, you could use: `printf ' - %s\n' "${pwd_ids[@]}"`; or to print two to a line in columns padded out to 20 spaces, `printf '%20s%20s\n' "${pwd_ids[@]}"`

---

Or, to put the values all on one line, pass them all in a single subsequent argument:

```
printf '%s\n' "${pwd_ids[*]}"
```

With the output (if your `IFS` variable is at its default or otherwise starts with a space):

```
E.1.1.7 E.1.1.9 E.1.1.2 E.1.1.3 E.1.1.4 E.1.1.6 E.1.1.5
```

---

To explain all the above: Subsequent arguments are substituted for placeholders in the format string. In the first case above, each element of your array is evaluated against `%s\n`, and thus has a newline added immediately after it.

In your question, you're passing `E.1.1.7` as a format string. This format string has no placeholders at all, so what the shell does with it is undefined: In your version of ksh, it prints the format string alone and ignores subsequent arguments; in other shells, it may print the format string (`E1.1.7`) once per argument, ignoring those arguments' values.